# How to subset multiple date ranges of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date-range

I have a dataframe with dates (and times) on the x-axis (the index). I'm trying to not plot a specific month in the graph, I want that month to just be blank. I have tried some stuff myself, and I can manage to plot only the data starting at a specific date, but can't manage to not plot specific dates. Let's say my dataframe is called df and it contains dates and times as index (DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS) and some values on the y-axis. I can manage to plot starting at a specific date by writing something like this before I plot:

```
df = df[df.index > '26-02-2016 00:00:00']
```

But when I try to write something like this (in an attempt to not plot anything from 26-01-2016 untill 26-02-2016):

```
df = df['26-01-2016 00:00:00'< df.index > '26-02-2016 00:00:00']
```

I just get error messages. Can anyone help me with this problem?
I have also tried reindexing but I do not get the result I want since it also filters out other parts of the graph.

Comment: I think you mean `'26-01-2016 00:00:00' > df.index > '26-02-2016 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `&`:

```
df = df['26-01-2016 00:00:00'< df.index & df.index > '26-02-2016 00:00:00']
```

Comment: I've tried this already. It gives me the following error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Hmmm ok, I just revisited the logic. Instead of `&` use `|` because both evaluations are true. If df.index is greater than '26-02-2016', then its also going to be greater than '26-01-2016'.

Answer (score 0):

> in an attempt to not plot anything from 26-01-2016 until 26-02-2016

If this is what you want you have mis-specified your constraint:

```
df = df[df.index < '26-01-2016 00:00:00' | df.index > '26-02-2016 00:00:00']
```